# First selected radio button always stays selected

Tags: twitter-bootstrap, radio-button

I'm trying to implement a very simple radio button select, but once I select a radio button, this button remains checked, even if I click on another one. Still, the other radio button's behavior (`data-toggle`) takes into action.

```
<div class="row">
<div class="col-md-offset-2 col-md-8">
    <section id="choice">
            <h3> Please choose </h3>

        <div class="col-md-5">
            <li class="plan">
                <ul>
                    <li>
                        <input type="radio" name="choice" id="id1" value="val1" data-toggle="tab" data-target="#1">First</input>
                    </li>
                    <li>
                        <input type="radio" name="choice" id="id2" value="val2" data-toggle="tab" data-target="#2">Second</input>
                    </li>
                    <li>
                        <input type="radio" name="choice" id="id3" value="val3" data-toggle="tab" data-target="#3">Third</input>
                    </li>
                </ul>
            </li>
        </div>
        <div class="tab-content col-md-7">
            <div class="tab-pane" id="1">
                <li class="plan">
                    <ul>
                        <li>Price: <b> 17,97 €</b>
                        </li>
                    </ul>
                </li>
            </div>
            <div class="tab-pane" id="2">
                <li class="plan">
                    <ul>
                        <li>Price: <b> 59,88 €</b>
                        </li>
                    </ul>
                </li>
            </div>
            <div class="tab-pane" id="3">
                <li class="plan">
                    <ul>
                        <li>Price: <b> 95,76 €</b>
                        </li>
                    </ul>
                </li>
            </div>
        </div>
    </section>
</div>
```

**Here's a fiddle:** http://jsfiddle.net/RWGRL/

Any ideas how to make this work?

Comment: Soo... Bootstrap does have docs on this.. But you should really just do something like this and follow their schema: http://jsfiddle.net/QLtsa/1/  And here is the documentation for this: http://getbootstrap.com/css/#forms-controls

Comment: @BuddhistBeast: in your example the content of the tab is not displayed after selecting a radio button

Comment: So really your question is related to generating a tab after checking a button, something your JSFiddle fails to demonstrate. Also, edit your question illustrating the functionality of the radios, you made the problem to be something different than proposed.

Comment: sorry, wrong fiddle link! edited my post!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just use jQuery to hide/show the data as the user clicks on the radio buttons. Here is your full HTML below:

**HTML**

```
<div class="row">
    <div class="col-md-offset-2 col-md-8">
        <section id="laufzeit">
                <h3> Please choose </h3>

            <div class="col-md-5">
                <div class="radio">
                    <label>
                        <input type="radio" class="option1" name="optionsRadios" id="optionsRadios1" value="option1">First</label>
                </div>
                <div class="radio">
                    <label>
                        <input type="radio" class="option2" name="optionsRadios" id="optionsRadios2" value="option2">Second</label>
                </div>
                <div class="radio">
                    <label>
                        <input type="radio" class="option3" name="optionsRadios" id="optionsRadios3" value="option3">Third</label>
                </div>
            </div>
            <div class="hide col-md-7" id="tester">
                <li class="plan">
                    <ul>
                        <li>Price: <b> 17,97 €</b>

                        </li>
                    </ul>
                </li>
                    </div>
                <div class="hide col-md-7" id="12month">
                    <li class="plan">
                        <ul>
                            <li>Price: <b> 59,88 €</b>

                            </li>
                        </ul>
                    </li>
                </div>
                <div class="hide col-md-7" id="24month">
                    <li class="plan">
                        <ul>
                            <li>Price: <b> 95,76 €</b>

                            </li>
                        </ul>
                    </li>
                </div>
            </div>
        </section>
    </div>
</div>
```

**jQuery**

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    $('.option1').click(function () {
        $('#12month').addClass('hide');
        $('#24month').addClass('hide');
        $('#tester').removeClass('hide');
    });
    $('.option2').click(function () {
        $('#tester').addClass('hide');
        $('#24month').addClass('hide');
        $('#12month').removeClass('hide');
    });
    $('.option3').click(function () {
        $('#tester').addClass('hide');
        $('#12month').addClass('hide');
        $('#24month').removeClass('hide');
    });
});
```

### **[DEMO JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/QLtsa/5/)**

Comment: Works fine! Thanks! I'd hoped it is possible with bootstrap's built-in functionalities. –

Answer (score 0):

data-toggle="tab" is used to generate tabs in bootstrap. Why would you apply that to a radio button? get rid of that, it should solve the problem .

Answer (score 0):

I changed

```
<input type="radio" name="choice" id="id1" value="val1" data-toggle="tab" data-target="#1">First</input>

<input type="radio" name="choice" id="id2" value="val2" data-toggle="tab" data-target="#2">Second</input>

<input type="radio" name="choice" id="id3" value="val3" data-toggle="tab" data-target="#3">Third</input>
```

to

```
<input type="radio" name="choice" id="id1" value="val1" data-target="#1">First</input>

<input type="radio" name="choice" id="id2" value="val2" data-target="#2">Second</input>

<input type="radio" name="choice" id="id3" value="val3" data-target="#3">Third</input>
```

and it began to work correctly for me.

Fiddle to show working: http://jsfiddle.net/gzEH9/

Comment: the radio buttons seem to work, but it does not show the content of the selected tab..